# Formatting comments is such a hassle

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, formatting, markdown

In this question: [Helper: loose vs. lose](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29847/39) I added a comment with the following markup:

```
clarification: by “should be pronounced *loss*” do you mean 
“should rhyme with *dose*” or “should rhyme with *boss*”? 
Wouldn’t a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word 
spelled *lose* to rhyme with *dose*?
```

I expected it to look something like this:

> clarification: by “should be pronounced *loss*” do you mean 
>       “should rhyme with *dose*” or “should rhyme with *boss*”? 
>       Wouldn’t a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word spelled 
>       *lose* to rhyme with *dose*?

Unfortunately it comes out looking like this:

> clarification: by “should be pronounced *loss*” do you mean “should
>   rhyme with *dose*” or “should rhyme with *boss*”? Wouldn’t a purely
>   rule-based phonetic expectation for a word spelled *lose* to rhyme with
>   *dose*?

Which is just awesomely terrible, embarrassingly bad. It makes me, as the commenter, look foolish. Seeing as how using HTML as a workaround is not possible in comments, is there any workaround so that my comments can be formatted correctly? Or is it really a “design choice” that you can only italicize some parts of comments but not others?

---

Update: I get the same issue if I used the “official” underscore syntax for italics in comment markup:

```
 clarification: by “should be pronounced _loss_” do you mean 
 “should rhyme with _dose_” or “should rhyme with _boss_”? 
 Wouldn’t a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word 
 spelled _lose_ to rhyme with _dose_?
```

resulting in this:

> clarification: by “should be pronounced *loss_” do you mean “should
>   rhyme with _dose_” or “should rhyme with _boss_”? Wouldn’t a purely
>   rule-based phonetic expectation for a word spelled _lose* to rhyme with
>   *dose*?

Comment: testing: by “should be pronounced _loss_” do you mean “should rhyme with *dose*” or “should rhyme with _boss_”? Wouldn't a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word spelled _lose_ to rhyme with *dose*?

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty bad. Whatever the regex is scanning for, something went wrong.

Comment: clarification: by "should be pronounced *loss*" do you mean 
"should rhyme with *dose*" or "should rhyme with *boss*"? 
Wouldn't a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word 
spelled *lose* to rhyme with *dose*?

Comment: I've also encountered this bug when trying to make something both **bold** and _italic_ at the same time, like this:  "**_both_**"  ...or this:  "_**both**_"

Comment: From memory, the same problem occurs in chat.

Comment: I see @Oded added the tag `status-bydesign` on 22 July, indicating that this is how the comment Markdown is designed to work. That seems utterly ludicrous to me. I run afoul of this arbitrary and extremely annoying ***bug*** in nearly half the comments I make. Why on earth would anyone _expect_ the Markdown to choke on typographically correct quotes, but do fine with incorrect quotes?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get away from "fancy quotes" there, because:

> clarification: by "should be pronounced *loss*" do you mean 
>   "should rhyme with *dose*" or "should rhyme with *boss*"? 
>   Wouldn't a purely rule-based phonetic expectation for a word 
>   spelled *lose* to rhyme with *dose*?

Works just fine.

Comment: Blech, straight quotes. Those are for programming, not English text. Almost as hideous as the incorrect parsing with proper quotes.

Comment: Interesting. Out of curiosity, how are the fancy quotes an impacting factor?

Comment: Fancy quotes?  Please clarify.

Comment: @Randolf, fancy quotes = curly quotes = “ ” instead of ". (On Windows “ = Alt+Num 0147, ” = Alt+Num 0148.)

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks!  (+1 for making that easy to understand.)

Comment: Anything that is detecting quote-characters in some other way than via the Unicode `Quotation_Mark=Yes` property (typically abbreviated `\p{qmark}` in regexes) is simply doing it wrong. Read: it’s a bug. There are 29 such code points, including both straight and curly quotes.  My hands are quite used to typing “Option-[” and “Shift-Option-[”, and ‘Option-]’ and ‘Shift-Option-]’; these is no reason for code to mess these up or to consider them second-class citizens. This is the 21ˢᵗ century: we should not be stuck with 19ᵗʰ century notions of typewriters.  Wake up and smell the Uɴɪᴄᴏᴅᴇ. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test comment above, it appears that the matching algorithm is greedily scanning for a closing match. Instead of finding the *nearest* Markdown close it is grabbing the *furthest* Markdown close.

Comment: apparently, it (1) ignores ANY special characters that are adjacent to “fancy” characters like open/close quotes and (2) it ignores potential closing special characters that appear *after* a space character.

Comment: _This is _a test.

Comment: Well, whadda-ya know.